# OKTA Authorization : Response 500

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, okta

I am trying to get authorization from OKTA API in Python.
Authentication works but I get response 500 when trying to get authorization.

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
auth_data = {
    "username": "mail@mail.com",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "options": {
        "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": False,
        "warnBeforePasswordExpired": False
    }
}
okta_response = active_session.post('https://<my_okta>/api/v1/authn', headers=headers,
                                    json=auth_data)
okta_json_response = json.loads(okta_response.content)
if okta_json_response['status'] != "SUCCESS":
    raise RuntimeError(f"Authentication failed")
else:
    print("Authentication is successful")
session_token = okta_json_response['sessionToken']
okta_app_authorize_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'client_id': '<my_client_id>',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://<my_website>/oauth2/callback',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'state': random.random(),
    'scope': 'openid profile',
    'sessionToken': session_token
})
okta_app_authorize_response = active_session.get('https://<my_okta>/oauth2/default/v1/authorize',
                                                 params=okta_app_authorize_data)
```

"Authentication is successful" is correctly printed but second request returns reponse 500 : Oops! Something went wrong. For more information contact your server administrator.

What can be the cause ?

Comment: I think you need `prompt=none` to be sent as well, but not sure if it's going to help to fix 500. Never seen that happening honestly. Check Okta syslog for any errors

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev prompt doesn't change anything unfortunately